# Range-based for loopで参照にした時としない時の速度面での違い

Tags: c++

Range-based for loopで参照にした時としないときではどのような違いがあるでしょうか。
特に速度的な面では違いがあるのでしょうか？例えばvectorをRange-based for loopで回す場合、単に値を書き換えることなく使う場合、通常のケースでは下記のどのケースが良いのでしょうか？直感的には3だと思われるのですが、今まで常に1を使っていました。

```
vector<string> vec =
{
    "foo", "bar", "baz"
};
// case 1
for ( auto it : vec )
{
    cout << it << endl;
}
// case 2
for ( auto &it : vec )
{
    cout << it << endl;
}
// case 3
for ( const auto &it : vec )
{
    cout << it << endl;
}
```

追記 -------------
皆さま、申し訳ございません。確かに質問として成り立っておりませんでした。
私のほうでCygwin上のgcc 4.8.3でのベンチマークを追記いたします。
100万行程度では差がほとんど見られなかったので
ランダムなアルファベット文字列1000万行のテキストで最適化オプションなしで
計測いたしました。

ケース1 参照なしのパターン

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> v;

    ifstream ifs("test_mil.txt");
    if (ifs.fail()) return -1;

    for (string line; getline(ifs, line); )
    {
        v.push_back(line);
    }

    const auto startTime = chrono::system_clock::now();

    string ss;
    int i = 0;
    for (auto s : v)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            ss = s.substr(i % s.size());    
        else
            ss = s;
        cout << (i % 2);
        i++;
    }
    cout << '\n';

    const auto endTime   = chrono::system_clock::now();
    const auto timeSpan = endTime - startTime;
    cout << "処理時間: "
     << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(timeSpan).count() 
     << " [ms]" << std::endl;

    cout << ss << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

ケース2 参照のパターン

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> v;

    ifstream ifs("test_mil.txt");
    if (ifs.fail()) return -1;

    for (string line; getline(ifs, line); )
    {
        v.push_back(line);
    }

    const auto startTime = chrono::system_clock::now();

    string ss;
    int i = 0;
    for (auto &s : v)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            ss = s.substr(i % s.size());    
        else
            ss = s;
        cout << (i % 2);
        i++;
    }
    cout << '\n';

    const auto endTime   = chrono::system_clock::now();
    const auto timeSpan = endTime - startTime;
    cout << "処理時間: "
     << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(timeSpan).count() 
     << " [ms]" << std::endl;

    cout << ss << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

計測結果：
ケース1  3123ms  3125ms  3135ms  平均 3128ms
ケース2  2944ms  2927ms  2935ms  平均 2935ms
ということでケース2のほうが速いことがわかりました。
また次のようなコードを書くと

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class mystring : public std::string {
public:

    mystring(const char *str) : std::string(str) { }

    // コピーコンストラクタ
    mystring(const mystring &rhs) : string(rhs.c_str())
    {
        cout << "mystring copy constructor" << endl;
    }

};

int main()
{
    vector<mystring> v;
    mystring m("abc");
    v.push_back(m);

    cout << "test start" << endl;
    for (auto &s : v)
    {
        cout << s << endl;
    }
    cout << "test end" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

このケースではコピーコンストラクタが呼び出されず、
for (auto s : v)としたほうではコピーコンストラクタが呼び出されました。
よって私の環境下につきましてはjoy1192さんの解答の通りとなりました。

Comment: 実際にベンチマークを取ればわかることだと思います。

Comment: それを言ってしまうとこのサイトの存在意義が・・・

Comment: 速度の良し悪しは予想はできても必ずしもその通りにはなりませんから、自分の環境で実測するのが最も適切です。コンパイラや実行環境、アーキテクチャすら指定されていないのですから、質問として成り立っていないと思います。

Comment: 最適化オプション無しで測定をしてもあまり意味はないです。最適化により速度が逆転する例は普通に存在します。一般論としてvector<T>のTはコピーしない方が良いと回答しましたが、最適化の結果バイナリからはループ自体が削除される等の場合もあるので、個別のケースに関してチューニングが必要な場合には実際に計測しましょう。

Comment: 要素数の割にケース1と2の速度差が小さいのが気になったのですが、各要素の文字列長は何文字くらいですか？数文字程度では[SSO(Small String Optimization)](http://cpplover.blogspot.jp/2013/12/c03c11_29.html)が効いて、本来の差異が見えにくくなります。また処理速度計測において「標準出力への出力」は非常に"重たい"処理です。たとえばファイルへのリダイレクトとして再計測すると、違った結果が見える可能性があります。（速度差が大きく出る可能性があります）

Comment: @yohjp さん 文字数はアルファベット小文字と大文字分の52文字で計測致しました。同じ文字列だとまずい気がしましたので気休め程度ですが、開始の文字は乱数からインデックスを与えてその文字からスタートさせて52文字にしています。確かにご指摘の通り妙に速度差が小さいですね。ファイルへリダイレクト試してみます。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 修正して異常に読みにくくなってますね。
初版の方がよかった

Answer (score 4, accepted):

case 2,case 3は用途によって使い分けるべきですが、一般的な使い方の上ではcase 1は遅くなります。

case 1の場合、
`vector<T>`の要素を1つ1つ`auto it`にコピーしていきます。つまり、毎回コピーコンストラクタが呼び出されるため、単純なアクセス用途であれば無駄なコストが発生します。
`for`ループ内でコピーした値に対して破壊的な操作を行いたい場合に使用するケースは有るでしょう。

case 2, case 3の場合、
`vector<T>`内の要素に対する参照を渡しているだけなので、高速です。
原理的にはポインタのコピー程度のコストしか発生しません。constの有無は速度には大きく関係しないはずです。

Answer (score 3):

質問文の要件にある通り、コンテナ型`vector<string>` かつ 要素書き換え無し ならば、 case 3:`cosnt auto&` 一択でよいでしょう。

一般的に case 3:`const auto&` と case 2:`auto&` とで速度的な差異は生じませんが、要素の書き換えを伴わないforループならば、コーディング誤りを防ぐためにもconst修飾指定が望ましいです。case 1:`auto` は、コンテナの要素型が基本型でもない限り避けるべきです。無駄な要素コピーによって速度的なペナルティを受けますし、要素型がコピー不可な場合はコンパイルエラーを引き起こします。

一般論としては、目的に応じ下記2種類を使い分けるのがベターです。

- `for (auto&& e : c)`：要素`e`を書き換える可能性がある
- `for (const auto& e : c)`：要素`e`を参照するだけ

関連情報として、次期C++標準（C++14の次）に向けて提案さていた、Terse Range-Based forの[初期提案文書](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3853.htm)にも次の言及があります。ただし、この提案は最終的に[却下されました](http://ezoeryou.github.io/blog/article/2014-12-11-tarse-range-based-for-removed-from-clang.html)。

> "for (auto elem : range)" is very tempting and very bad. It produces "auto elem = *__begin;" (see 6.5.4 [stmt.ranged]/1), which copies each element, which is bad because:
>
> - It might not compile - [...]
> - It might misbehave at runtime - [...]
> - It might be inefficient - [...]

余談ですが：`for (～ it : vec)`の変数名`it`はイテレータを連想させる名前なので、`s(tr)`とか`e(lem)`の方が良いかもしれませんね。